# create hive table from position delimited files

Tags: c#, json, hadoop, hive, csv

We are currently trying to analyze a number of position delimited files via HIVE and SPARK.  These files have an inherit hierarchical structure.  To define our hive schema, we are currently converting the position delimited files to JSON via C#.

My question is whether it is possible to define a hive schema directly on a positional file in the HDFS rather than having to first convert it to JSON.

**Because i am unable to provide the source documents or current code for privacy purposes, i was hoping someone can provide a general direction or information source rather than exact syntax.  I tried researching the topic extensively but was not able to find any instances of a hive schema defined directly on a positional file.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: By position delimited files, are you referring to a flat file with each entry in the same position with the same delimiter?

Comment: Hey Brandon, sorry for the delay.  Just got back from my honeymoon :).  Anyway, yes, the files are flat files with the position indicating the field name.  For example, record position of 1-2 is 'Record Sequence Code' ; position 4-10 is a 'Correction Interval Start Date' etc.

Comment: I don't fully understand how your files are delimited, but you may have a few options.  You can create your table defining a delimiter (if it's simple) with `... ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'...` which would be for tab delimited fields.  Another option may be to use RegEx serde.  See : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-ApacheWeblogData.  And finally, you may be able to use a CustomSerde.  See : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe